# Python sql query insert data in columns

Tags: python, sql

I'm not so familiar with SQL. I have a table with over 100 columns. What is the best way to insert data from a dictionary into the corresponding column of my table (key and column names are identical)?

Example:

My SQL Table

Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4 Column5

My data which I get from a dictionary:

First Data set

Column2:apple, Column4:tree

Second Data set

Column1:banana, Column2:blue, Column3:green, Column4:house, Column5:red

So if the key of the dictionary is identical to the column name of the table, the data should be inserted. I know how to do this for a single query but how can I do this (clever) for a large number of queries?

Thanks!

Edit:

What I would do at a single level and some clarifications:

1) Create a SQL Table with all 120 columns but without any data.
2) I have about 500 word files which contain a part of the data which should go into the database (about 5-10 from the 120 columns). 
3) So I have to read them, parse them and if the key of the data in the dictionary match any of the 120 column names, the value should be inserted.
3) Single mode:

```
if key == 'Column1':
```

sql = INSERT INTO Column1 
valuexy

This is of course very stupid for 500 files and 120 columns. I hope this was more clear.

Comment: Could you share what you've got to do it for a single query? Then it'll be easier for people to show you how to adapt it for many queries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say you have the following dict:

```
query_data = {
    'col1': 56,
    'col2': 100,
    'col3': 'lol'
}
```

Your sql query could be constructed as following:

```
sql = 'INSERT INTO table_name ({fields}) VALUES ({values})'
```

Now you have to construct the fields string

```
fields = query_data.keys()
fields_string = ', '.join(fields)
```

and for the values you do something similar, using the already created fields lists. (This could be done in another way if your dictionary was an OrderedDict).

```
values_string = ', '.join(['"{0}"'.format(query_data[key]) for key in fields])
```

Finally you can compose the string.

```
composed_sql = sql.format(fields=fields_string, values=values_string)
```

This is a very rough method, but very understandable if you are new to this topic. Most of frameworks allow for much refined methods to achieve this. Especially as to SQL injections.

Print it, play around, understand the concepts and with time you'll probably use other ways.

**EDIT**

A more succinct way would be:

```
sql = 'INSERT INTO table_name ({fields}) VALUES ({values})'
fields = ', '.join(query_data.keys())
values = ', '.join(['"{0}"'.format(value) for value in query_data.values()])
composed_sql = sql.format(fields=fields, values=values)
```

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion, can you tell me where is the mistake?

Comment: Sorry, Rodas was right. I thought since Dicts don't have order, keys() and values() could return in different order. But fact is, they don't. I'll edit to use that approach since it is a little bit cleaner. map() is anyway "deprecated", and you can't add quotes, so unless you are inserting only numbers, your query will crash.

Answer (score 2):

You can concatenate the keys and the values of the dictionary with `join()` and `map()`:

```
d = {'Column1':'banana', 'Column2':'blue', 'Column3':'green', 'Column4':'house', 'Column5':'red'}
columns = ', '.join(map(str, d.keys()))
values = ', '.join(map(repr, d.values()))
cursor.execute("INSER INTO table ({}) VALUES ({})".format(columns, values))
```

Comment: This is a bad solution. Nobody guarantees that the .keys() and .values() are in the same order since dictionaries are not ordered. Besides, map() is dis-recommended, you should use generators instead. **edit** no, I was wrong. keys and values are returned in the same order.

Comment: Ok! One more question is it a good habit to leave the rest "empty" (NULL)?

Comment: columns = ', '.join(d.keys()) is good enough. @ikaros45: why is map "dis-recommended"? {}{} means {0}{1}, and 0,1 means 1st and 2nd argument, columns, and values, thus.

Comment: @snowflake `{}` is used to be replaced with the arguments of `format()`. Keys and values are returned in the same order, and `map` is a built-in function as valid as any other. It may not the better solution, but at least these aren't the main problems ;)

Comment: @koriander List comprehensions (not generators, sorry) provide a syntax cleaner than map(), reduce()..., without messing with lambda functions and easier nesting, etc. It's just more pythonic.

Comment: @ikaros45 I disagree. Functional programming provides very elegant and clear solutions, and I'm sure they are more pythonic than nested comprehension lists. You can take a look at some posts of the [tag:python] tag to confirm it.

Comment: @A.Rodas You can be very well right, I'm not very familiar with functional programming. But I would say for this very case (add quotes to the values), the comprehension is clearer and more pythonist. And... even more for beginners.